# Import Data from Excel with Cell color

Tags: database, vb.net, excel, datagridview

I am creating a database which collects data from an excel file the import is happening fairly easily but the cell colors when imported take way too much time as I am currently setting the color for the cells one-by-one.

Is there a way to get around this and import the color, font, forecolor, etc. data as a dataset along with the datatable for displaying in the dgv.

The code I have so far is:

```
obooks = oexcel.ActiveWorkbook
path = obooks.FullName
osheet = obooks.Worksheets(e.Node.Text)
osheet.Activate()
sheetname = "[" + e.Node.Text + "$]"
myconnection = New  System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + " ;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1'")
    mycommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from " & sheetname, myconnection)
    dataset = New System.Data.DataSet
    mycommand.Fill(dataset)
    workspace_data.DataSource = dataset.Tables(0)
    'workspace_data.DataSource = databind.
    myconnection.Close()
    For Me.i = 0 To workspace_data.Rows.Count - 1
        For Me.j = 0 To workspace_data.Columns.Count - 1
            With workspace_data.Rows(i).Cells(j)
                .Style.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromOle(osheet.UsedRange.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Interior.color)
            End With
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: It is probably the setting of each of your grid cell colours that is taking the time. Try making the grid invisible while you update it, or using virtual mode, or painting the back colour in the cellpainting event

Comment: thanks i tried the DatagridView.Visible method and that increased the speed drastically but i am unable to understand the cellpainting event. How do you propose should I use that.